# ERROR in Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined

Tags: angular

When I upgrade to Angular 4 and run ng serve, I got the following error:

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined
```

The dependencies are used as per following

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.8",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "codelyzer": "^2.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.7.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.3",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
```

Is  there something wrong here?

Comment: Where is `getSymbolByModule` being used/called?

Answer (score 21):

You need to update @angular/compiler-cli to version 4 as well.

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest particular version. The important thing is to install same version of "@angular/compiler-cli" as "@angular/compiler"

Comment: As @MateuszMoska says it has to be the same version of _compiler_ and _compiler-cli_ package. This worked for me.

Comment: @angular/compiler-cli 4.0.0 was broken for me, but pinning 4.0.2 worked.

I wish angular wasn't so fickle.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue relative to `@angular/platform-browser`. 
There is a conflict between your `@angular/platform-browser` and your `@angular/cli` version. Try to update your angular/cli  to latest. Same issue was discussed  [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5940)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have followed the instruction in that discussion but it still does not work. Is it because angular/cli 1.0 does not support Angular 4?

Comment: make sure you also update to at least angular/cli 1.01

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I also had a version of angular-cli in my `devDependencies`. I removed that and ng-serve worked.